# Appeals system for failed audits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

Having seen how some people get up-tight about failing a review audit ... and complain about it on the meta site ... here's a suggestion.

If you have watched tennis, football (various kinds), cricket and so on the telly recently, you can't have missed that they allow players to appeal certain umpire calls.

- If an appeal succeeds, the umpire's ruling is reversed, and the player retains the right to make another appeal.
- If an appeal fails, the umpire's ruling stands, and the player loses his appeal right; e.g. until the next set (tennis) or innings (cricket).

My suggestion is to apply appeals to failed audits:

- When you fail an audit, you can choose to "appeal".
- If you decide to appeal, you get to write a short explanation of why you are appealing.  Then you submit your appeal.
- The appeal goes to the moderators. A moderator looks at the audit, and your appeal explanation.

  - If he / she upholds your appeal, you get your "appeal" back and the failed audit is reversed.  And (ideally) the bad audit question is fixed or withdrawn.
  - If he / she refuses your appeal, you lose your right to appeal.

The "right of appeal" could be limited to people above a given reputation.  That would limit the extra workload for moderators.

When someone loses an appeal, they could get the "right of appeal" back after a period, or after a number of passed audits.

Comment: Brilliant! And then questions about failed audits on Meta could be closed? I just hope it won't lead to new type of questions about rejected appeals

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes.  Brad has already suggested the same thing.  Should I delete this?

Comment: @StephenC keep it, so it gets more attention

Comment: I had exactly this idea on my mind for a long time but I never got around positing it. Thanks for doing so!

Comment: @StephenC Since this is a *different* feature request than the one Brad was responding to with his suggestion, it's important (I think) that it be a separate question.

Comment: I've also had this in mind for quite some time, but felt it would be dismissed as "only applies to edge cases".

Comment: And don't forget about a process to appeal the results of the appeal.  And another process to appeal the results of *that* appeal.  And so on... Or, people could just *stop being so uptight about failed audits.*  Yes, it's insulting when you fail a bad audit - I get it, really, I do.  But just click "ok" and move on, already.

Comment: @JeffLoughlin I get you are trying to make a joke, but I don't see why one would need to appeal removal of bad audit from almost infinite pool of audits... Most Meta posts are about non-passable audits which makes people upset and not about occasional failed audit...

Comment: It may be good idea to get overall number of failed audits to see how careful we should be about allowing appeals. If overall number is low enough (comparable to custom flags for example) some basic "one appeal a week" may be enough, otherwise some more complex rules would be needed to avoid potentially flooding mods.

Comment: I've twice asked on meta for an appeal process to promote removal of bad review questions.  In the absence of such a system, I simply choose to spend my SO time where I can be more productive.  I'm not particularly insulted; it's just that trying to "learn" from an invalid review failure wastes time.  Getting banned and changing my participation habits wastes time.  I simply quit reviewing until the system works better.

Comment: Next step: The appeal gets rejected 95% of the time because the user just wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @Cerbrus - That's OK.  If the inattentive user loses his appeal, he won't get another one for N weeks, or M successful audits or something.

Comment: @StephenC: My point is that it's a significant amount of extra work for mods. Is that really warranted?

Comment: @Cerbrus - Arguably, no.  Maybe the better solution is to instruct the people who hate failed audits to stop complaining about it :-)

Comment: I'd say so, aye.